# Temporary REST server for client development

Tags: web-development, chrome, web-apis

[Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) is a great test tool for developing a REST server. Without this, I had to make a request using `curl` in command line. `curl` is not hard to use. But `Advanced REST client` is not only super easy to use but full-featured. Moreover I do not need to develop a client to test it.

The problem was developing *client* while *server* was also in progress. I could not find the test method. I wrote this code to capture all requests using [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/). This program returns necessary information with `Content-Type: application/json`.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''}, methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def echo(path):
    return jsonify(headers=str(request.headers),
                   args=request.args,
                   form=request.form,
                   method=request.method,
                   path=request.path,
                   url=request.url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My question is: **Is there a server version analogous to Advanced REST client?**

Note that: This question is transferred from SO and Web Applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you want something that will mock the server response for you. Which mocking method depends on what you're using to develop your client. I've used [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) for Java client development. There is a [Mockito for Python](http://code.google.com/p/mockito-python/) but I've not used it. From the documentation it looks like it provides the same feature set that the Java version does.

Mockito lets you replace an object with a mock object that only returns what you tell it to.
So for example, you could temporarily replace your call to jsonify with a mock method that will return a json string containing some test data instead of trying to communicate with the server that isn't there.

Also, questions about code mocking are absolutely on topic at SO.